# How to solve crashes on scrolling UITableview which has custom cell?

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, uitableview, xib

My app crashes while scrolling UITableview which has custom cell but works fine on simulators.

Below is my code

```
    -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath // Values of each cell

    {
        static NSString *cellidentifier = @"cellidentifier";
        TableCell *cell = (TableCell*) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellidentifier];
        //NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        //cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        cell = (TableCell *) [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TableCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];

        if (cell == nil) 
        {
            cell = [[[TableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellidentifier] autorelease];                

        }

        cell.lblname.text = [name objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.lblphone.text = [phone objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.lbladdress.text =[address objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        NSData * photodata=[photo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.imgphoto.image=[UIImage imageWithData:photodata];        

        return cell;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you include the crash message in the console?

Comment: Error "Received memory warning" but it works fine on simulators, crashes on iphone

Comment: I think because you didn't reuse your cell so it quickly increases memory usage if you have many cells, and on simulator it has large amount of memory, when on device it doesn't. Check out my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your tableView doesn't reuse cell at all. Because you reassign `cell` after call `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`. Your code should be:

```
static NSString *cellidentifier = @"cellidentifier";
TableCell *cell = (TableCell*) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellidentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
//NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TableCell" owner:self options:nil];
//cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

if (!cell) {
    cell = (TableCell *) [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TableCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

Comment: it says "instance method dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:indexPath not found (return type defaults to id)"

Comment: What is your deployment target? Which version of iOS? This method is available from iOS 6.0. And I checked, there's no typo here. When you type that line, does Xcode give you a auto-completion for that method?

Comment: even if run on xcode  it shows error telling "UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xf3e3800

2015-10-26 13:00:10.233 Rotary[383:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xf3e3800'

Comment: *** First throw call stack:

(0x35b6988f 0x3378d259 0x35b6ca9b 0x35b6b915 0x35ac6650 0xdac93 0x332c9efb 0x332c8fd9 0x332c8763 0x3326cf37 0x35ac81fb 0x32c93aa5 0x32c936bd 0x32c97843 0x32c9757f 0x32c8f4b9 0x35b3db1b 0x35b3bd57 0x35b3c0b1 0x35abf4a5 0x35abf36d 0x3385a439 0x33297cd5 0xd659b 0xd6530)

terminate called throwing an exceptionMessage from debugger: failed to send the k packet"